# Instagram API Client ID vs App ID vs Instagram App ID vs Client Secret

Tags: react-native, instagram-api, react-native-instagram-login

I registered with Facebook Developer and set up my instagram app but I am not sure where to find my client id...I can see my App ID, my Instagram App ID and my Client Secret but there is nothing with my "client id" listed. Are one of these actually my client id? Do I need to sign up for something more then Instagram Basic Display API?

Is there any documentation breaking down what each of these IDs are used for?

I am not finding any in either of these documentations: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/ or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/

Answer (score 2):

The old Instagram API used Client ID.  For the new Instagram Graph API, you only need the Instagram App ID and Secret App Id.

1. You redirect to Instagram using your Instagram App ID.
2. Once the user authorizes your app, Instagram will redirect back to your app.
3. You use your Instagram App ID, Secret App ID, and the code Instagram sends you after the redirect to get a token.
4. You use the token to get the user's photos, etc.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions